# Python async events and serial async?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have code (python class, I'll call it `Arduino`) that writes control packets to a serial port (using `serial_asyncio`), and the serial port replies with confirmation packets. However the remote device also sends event packets to the python side randomly. I want the class to provide the decoded packets to the class that instantiates my class (I'll call it `Controller`). I am confused on how to handle this.

My first thought is to provide callback to the Arduino class:

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arduino = Arduino("/dex/ttyS0", self._serialPacketCallback)

    def _serialPacketCallback(self, obj: dict):
        pass # handle spontaneous event packet from remote
```

But this does not seem very async-y. What is the asyncio way to do this? I think this would look like:

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arduino = Arduino("/dex/ttyS0")

    async readEventPacket(self):
        pass

    #somewhere, not sure where, or how to start it:
    async def _handleEvents(self)
        while True:
            event = await self._readEventPacket()

    async def start(self):
        await self.arduino.start()
        await asyncio.wait([self._handleEvents()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = Controller()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(controller.start())    
    loop.run_forever()
```

I've looked around and I've seen suggestions of using **callbacks**, **multi-processing pipes**, **additional event loops**, and I am sure they work, but I'm not sure what the proper approach is. For me, I don't want to start any additional event loops or threads, leading me to think the callback is best, but that is not very async, and I would like to know how to do this as async, without additional event loops or callbacks.

An additional concern that I want to articulate is that I'd like this as loosely coupled as the `Arduino` class will be used in other controllers.

Side note: I am not sure when in Python a new event loop is required to be created?

Another question: how does the `Arduino` class generate an event and have `Controller` pick it up in `await self._readEventPacket()`?

Comment: I'm writing this as a general comment, not an answer, because I don't understand your classes. Async mean you don't wait for I/O, but you respond to events like a channel is ready to send or new data has arrived. That's why a callback is just fine. One event loop is all an async program needs.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between a confirmation packet and a random event packet?  Do they have some header information, or is there some way to parse them?  Otherwise your arduino object will have no way of knowing when it gets a reply and when it gets random data.  Also, you want to "provide" the decoded packets to Controller.  Does that mean something more than just calling a function in the Controller class, passing the decoded packet as an argument?  Do you need to logically associate each confirmation packet to its corresponding control packet?

Comment: The short answer is packet has an `opcode` and the opcodes for the event packets are different from the control packets. Also the confirmation packet is identical to the control packet, so it just echoes back the control packet, meaning that we can compare the last packet sent with the last packet received.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about asyncio is that you can always convert a callback-based interface to a coroutine-based one, and vice versa.

Let's assume your `Arduino` class implements a callback-based interface, like this (untested):

```
class Arduino:
    def __init__(self, device, callback):
        self._device = device
        self._callback = callback

    async def start(self):
        reader, writer = await serial_asyncio.connect(url=self._device, baudrate=115200)
        while True:
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            self._callback(data)
```

You can convert that interface into a coroutine-based one by using a queue:

```
def callback_to_coro():
    # Return two functions, one that can be passed as callback to
    # code that expects it, and the other a coroutine that can be
    # awaited to get the values the callback was invoked with.
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    return queue.put_nowait, queue.get
```

With that code you can implement `Controller.read_event_packet` like this:

```
class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
        callback, wait = callback_to_coro()
        self.arduino = Arduino("/dex/ttyS0", callback)
        self.read_event_packet = wait
```